# Retrieving a file outside root, avoid cutting off filename which contain spaces

Tags: php

I have uploaded files to a folder outside my webroot folder and use some php code to retrieve the file after being authenticated by database. My code below seems to work, i.e. retrieves the file, the only issue I have is, the pdfs uploaded contain filenames with spaces and the code below seems to only retrieve the first word before the space.

The example filenames are
My Trip To London.pdf
Wildlife Photography Part 1.pdf

Apart from going through the database and phuycical files and substituting each file to contain an underscore instead of a space, is there a way I can alter the code below so it retrieves the whole filename?

I thought I could substitute the filename with with %20 if it detected a space but that doesn't work.

```
/* Done some processing above to retrieve the $filename for the pdf */

$file = 'h:'.$filename;


header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the pdfs uploaded contain filenames with spaces and the code below seems to only retrieve the first word before the space.

Quote the name:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
```

or in clearer form:

```
header(sprintf('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="%s"', basename($file)));
```